# How to have 2 select inputs with exclusive elements?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html, react-select

Let's say I have two select inputs. Both of them have the same 5 fruits.
The two select inputs are 'Fruits I love' and 'Fruits I hate'.

```
//  This code is a sample code to describe the problem

<select name='lovedFruits'>
    <option value='Apple'>Apple</option>
    <option value='Orange'>Orange</option>
    <option value='Mango'>Mango</option>
    <option value='Grapes'>Grapes</option>
    <option value='Watermelon'>Watermelon</option>
</select>

<select name='hatedFruits'>
    <option value='Apple'>Apple</option>
    <option value='Orange'>Orange</option>
    <option value='Mango'>Mango</option>
    <option value='Grapes'>Grapes</option>
    <option value='Watermelon'>Watermelon</option>
</select>
```

These are multi select inputs (I'm using react-select v1 for this, it is an old project that requires few changes).

What I want is that if I select Apple and Grapes in first select, they should be disabled or hidden from the second select element.

Is there a feasible way to achieve this? I've not been able to find or come up with anything.

```
//  --------- Demo React Select code ----------

fruits = [
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple'}
    {label: 'Orange', value: 'Orange'}
    {label: 'Mango', value: 'Mango'}
    {label: 'Grapes', value: 'Grapes'}
    {label: 'Watermelon', value: 'Watermelon'}
]

<Field 
    name='fruitsILove'

    selectConfig={
        closeOnSelect: false,
        disabled: false,
        multi: true,
        simpleValue: false,
        removeSelected: true,
    }
    options={fruits}
/>

<Field 
    name='fruitsIHate'
    selectConfig={
        closeOnSelect: false,
        component={renderSelect}
        disabled: false,
        multi: true,
        simpleValue: false,
        removeSelected: true,
    }
    options={fruits}
/>
```

Comment: Can you should an example using react-select? I guess you're passing the `Select` component a list of options to render, but I want to make sure.

Comment: Yeah, I just did that. Hope it makes the problem clearer to understand!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by maintaining two lists with same fruits. Now, as a user start selecting from favorite fruits, keep removing those fruits from hatedFruits list. So, when the user clicks on the hated fruits list, he will only see the fruits which he left unchecked in the previous list.

```
let fruits = [
    {label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple'}
    {label: 'Orange', value: 'Orange'}
    {label: 'Mango', value: 'Mango'}
    {label: 'Grapes', value: 'Grapes'}
    {label: 'Watermelon', value: 'Watermelon'}
];

let favoriteFruits = fruits.slice();
let hatedFruits = fruits.slice();
```

Remove the fruits selected in *favoriteFruits* list from *hatedFruits* list.

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I would store my values in state and then trim the `value` props like the following example:

```
const fruits = [
  { label: "Apple", value: "Apple" },
  { label: "Orange", value: "Orange" },
  { label: "Mango", value: "Mango" },
  { label: "Grapes", value: "Grapes" },
  { label: "Watermelon", value: "Watermelon" }
];

const selectNames = ["fruitsILove", "fruitsIHate"];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fruitsILove: [],
      fruitsIHate: []
    };
  }
  onChange = (value, { name }) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  trimValues(name) {
    const toRemove = this.state[
      name === "fruitsILove" ? "fruitsIHate" : "fruitsILove"
    ];

    // Depending of your UX you can remove the props or disable it
    // return fruits.filter(val => toRemove.indexOf(val) === -1);

    return fruits.map(val =>
      toRemove.indexOf(val) === -1 ? val : { ...val, isDisabled: true }
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {selectNames.map(name => (
          <Select
            isMulti
            key={name}
            name={name}
            onChange={this.onChange}
            options={this.trimValues(name)}
            value={this.state[name]}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/n50nz6xjjp).